# JPQL: Switch/case when an object does not exist on the database

Tags: sql, spring, hibernate, spring-data, jpql

I am writing an `@Query` for a repository method. This query should return all `Movie` which have an average `Rating` less than the given parameters value:

```
@Query(value =
    "select m from Movie m " +
    "where (select avg(r.rating) from Review r " +
    "where m.id = r.movie.id) < :rating")
List<Movie> findMoviesWithAverageRatingLowerThan(@Param("rating") Double rating);
```

The problem is that I have a requirement that when a `Movie` has no ratings, it should be interpreted as an average rating equal `0`.

I have a clue that I should use `switch/case` combined with `when`, but as for now I have no idea how to do it.

Is this even possible to achieve this in one query?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [COALESCE](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#_coalesce_expressions) expression like below:

```java
@Query(value =
    "select m from Movie m " +
    "where (select avg(COALESCE(r.rating, 0)) from Review r " +
    "where m.id = r.movie.id) < :rating")
List<Movie> findMoviesWithAverageRatingLowerThan(@Param("rating") Double rating);
```